# Getting value from field in DataTable when column name has spaces

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, datatable, system.data

I have tried:

```
ObjDTOleDBNFeIntegra.Rows(I)("[Cnpj Cpf]").ToString() //with brackets  
ObjDTOleDBNFeIntegra.Rows(I)("'Cnpj Cpf'").ToString() //with apostrophe  
ObjDTOleDBNFeIntegra.Rows(I)("Cnpj Cpf").ToString() //without anything
```

I'm using VB.NET, but comments with apostrophes in here don't seem to be identified.

And I get the exceptions for each case:
<kbd>Column '[Cnpj Cpf]' does not belong to table Table.</kbd> (fail)
<kbd>Column 'Cnpj Cpf' does not belong to table Table.</kbd>      (fail)
<kbd>Column ''Cnpj Cpf'' does not belong to table Table.</kbd> (fail)

What should I do in order to ger a value from a field in a dataTable when the column name has spaces ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you checked what the *column* thinks it is called? It might have underscores, for example. Loop over the columns and find out (sorry, examples in C#):

```
foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns) {
    Debug.WriteLine(col.ColumnName);
}
```

Actually, it is faster to use the column if you are doing it in a loop, so I might use something like:

```
DataColumn col = table.Columns["whatever"];
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows) {
    Console.WriteLine(row[col]);
}
```